# Running Python from Virtual environment?

Tags: python, bash, virtual

Created virtual environment in `~/python/venv/venv_python2` folder.

I can run `python` in a regular way (for venvs):

```
source ~/python/venv/venv_python2/bin/activate
python
```

or I can run python with:

```
~/python/venv/venv_python2/bin/python
```

What is a difference between 2 above?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

You can check where `python` is running from by typing `which python` in bash. You'll see that it points to your virtual env when you're in it.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to double-check there is nothing else happening with `source ...` command besides pointing to a python location.

Comment: It also sets up Python's library path to prefer, or even only use, libraries installed in the virtualenv.

Comment: So `source` part is important if there are libraries installed, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the virtual environment is to isolate the dependencies inside it so you don't have to worry about knowing the precise path to the correct Python interpreter or the libraries you have installed. So while using the absolute path is technically not incorrect, it completely bypasses the facilities of the virtualenv, and could eventually end up pointing to the wrong location if you hardcode it in a script today, and decide to move, migrate, or refactor your virtualenv tomorrow.

Comment: I agree with later statement. However I had issue. For example - I could install cx_Oracle without problem in Virtual Environment. But when running Jython which calls python script and executes python in Venv - it has problems connecting to Oracle (complaining about some libraries). I then `deactivated` environment, set my `python` link to virtual env python (link on my computer) and let Jython run - no problem this time.. Not sure why it works this way..

Comment: Because you forgot to install something which Oracle needs in your virtualenv?

Comment: Let me repeat - it WORKS in my virtual environment when I do `source ..venv...` but DOES NOT WORK when is sourced and e.g. outside Jython calls it. But it WORKS when outside Jython calls direct link to python in VENV.. Beats me..

Comment: So your real question appears to be "how do I use Jython in a virtualenv"? I'm not competent to answer that really but I imagine you need to tweak the Java classpath inside the virtualenv, too.

Comment: Googling for a bit, does it workeif you create a new virtualenv with `virtualenv -p jython newenv`?

Comment: Never tried it but I will (never knew -p and jython can be parameters for creating venv)..

Answer (score 0):

There is a very slight, almost irrelevant difference between the two:

1. `~/python/venv/venv_python2/bin/python` specifies *exactly* which Python interpreter you want to use.
2. `python` runs which ever interpreter is found *first* when examining your path.

One of the things that `source ~/python/venv/venv_python2/bin/activate` does is that it puts `~/python/venv/venv_python2/bin` at the front of your path, so that when you run `/`-free command, the first place the shell looks is that directory, meaning `python` will resolve to the one in your virtual environment.

So, the only way your two ways would differ is if something else modified your `PATH` in the meantime.